# Loop through PDF and save all pages into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pypdf

I am fairly new to Python and trying the PyPDF2 package for the first time. I simply want to loop through my PDF document (66 pages) and extract all the text into a DataFrame.

I have followed some blog posts (http://echrislynch.com/2018/07/13/turning-a-pdf-into-a-pandas-dataframe/) and have the following code. Unlike the blog post, I am not interested in any data cleanse or transformation at this point, I simply want the pages stored in a dataframe. :

```
import PyPDF2
import os
import pandas as pd

# Open  PDF as an object and read it into PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('MyReport.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

# loop through pages
pages=list()
for i in range(1, pdfReader.numPages):
   pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
   page = pageObj.extractText()
   page = page[0:]
   pages.append(page[0:])
for i in range(1,len(page)):
   pages=[page[2:] for page in pages]

# Create dataframe
page_df = pd.DataFrame([page])

# Concat with dbn_df
MyNewReport= pd.DataFrame([page])
page_df = page_df.iloc[0:]
MyNewReport= pd.concat([MyNewReport,page_df], axis=0, 
                         ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

I am encountering an error :

```
File "<ipython-input-78-729b84e346f9>", line 16, in <module>
page[i] = page[i][2:]

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

So I know the issue lies with my loop, although looking at the variable explorer, my dataframe contains the text from the last page of my pdf...so it is looping through something!

Can anyone help or recommend some further reading to understand the error and resolution?

Comment: Interesting stuff! I guess your page variable contains a string and by doing page[i]= ... you would try to assign something to the ith element of the string, but strings don't like to be changed that way at all, so they respond with an error.

Comment: You probably wanted to create a list of pages, right? so do something like "pages=list()" and in your first loop do "pages.append(page[0:])" and instead of your second loop: "pages=[page[2:] for page in pages]". Btw. you could of course do that in one step.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jotbe! Your recommendation removed the error message for me, however I am still only getting the last page of the PDF stored in the DF? Possible a problem with my indentation?  I have edited the original post to show the code

Comment: That's because you also have to change "page_df = pd.DataFrame([page])". page is the variable that is set in each iteration of your loop. If you use it after the loop finished, it will contain the value of the last iteration (so the very last page processed). Instead of your code, you should try "page_df = pd.DataFrame({'page': pages})". But this should put each page into one row of the dataframe. I don't know if that is what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Jottbe! Thank you for all your help!